# Android Error sending ArrayList<ParseObject> in between Activities on Android. Parcel: unable to marshal value com.parse.ParseObject@b308c828 error

Tags: android, arraylist, parse-platform, parcelable, parcel

I'm trying to send an arrayList of ParseObjects from one activity to another with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("arrayList", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

where list is the arrayList of ParseObjects obtained from a parse query denoted by ArrayList. Some of the ParseObjects are unParcebale as they contain ParseFile and Location data.

I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.parse.ParseObject@b308c828
```

How do I get rid of this error and successfully send and then obtain the ArrayList in the second Activity?
Thanks

Comment: One of the `parseObject` members must not be `Parcelable`.

Comment: @nstCactus indeed. It contains a parseFILE. What should I do?

Comment: @IreAdewolu I posted what you should do in the answer below. Personally, I would recommend using JSON or GSON. There's also a "hackish" solution which I deliberately didn't mention in my answer: Using a public static class to simply store the list in one activity and retrieve it in the other. Sadly, it's also the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3):

[ParseObject](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/) is either not Serializable nor Parcelable. You have to use a custom wrapper to send the data you want and rebuild your ParseObject on the new Activity.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can pass something to other Activities (nor Fragments) that is not one of the [types shown here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). Most importantly, objects you want to pass have to be either Serializable or Parcelable. Try [Jamie Chapman's ParseProxyObject](https://gist.github.com/jamiechapman/5375115), which wraps ParseObject in a Serializable, found [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/passing-around-parseobjects-in-android). But please check the [documentation of Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) first:

> **Implement Serializable Judiciously**
>
> Refer to Effective Java's chapter on serialization for thorough coverage of the serialization API. The book explains how to use this interface without harming your application's maintainability.
>
> **Recommended Alternatives**
>
> JSON is concise, human-readable and efficient. Android includes both a streaming API and a tree API to read and write JSON. Use a binding library like GSON to read and write Java objects directly.